# How to build dictionary from two lists

Tags: python

With two lists of different sizes:

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
cities=['LA','NY','SF']
```

I need to get this:

```
result={1:'LA', 2:'NY', 3:'SF'}
```

I thought of doing it with:

```
result={number:cities[numbers.index(number)] for number in numbers if numbers.index(number)<len(cities)}
```

But this one-liner gets kind of long. I wonder if there is an alternative way of achieving the same goal.

## EDITED LATER:

There were multiple suggestions made to use `zip`:

```
dict(zip(cities, numbers))
```

While it is a definitely a simpler syntax than list comprehension I've used I wonder which would be faster to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip`, it will only zip upto the end of the shortest sequence

```
dict(zip(cities, numbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
cities=['LA','NY','SF']
dict(zip(cities,numbers))
```

;)

I suspect it is duplicate though - search before you post

Comment: If its a duplicate "they" are usually quick on letting know it is!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably `dict(zip(numbers,cities))`
zip will stop once any of the lists ends, which is what you want.